# Как выполнить инкремент значения NULL в MySQL?

Tags: mysql, null, инкремент

Есть запрос:

```
UPDATE table_name SET `field_summ`=`field_summ`+1 WHERE `number` = '5'
```

Так вот, если в поле `field_summ` установлено значение `NULL`, то инкремент значения в данном поле не происходит.
Но если туда внести хотя бы ноль или единицу, то всё начинает работать.
Как быть?
Ставить данному полю NOT NULL в БД, или есть способ всё-таки на уровне запроса?

Answer (score 1):

Используй функцию IFNULL(field_summ,0).То есть в твоем запросе это будет выглядеть так:

```
UPDATE table_name SET `field_summ`=ifnull(`field_summ`, 0)+1 WHERE `number` = '5'
```

Comment: лучше `coalesce(field_sum, 0)`, ибо `coalesce` вроде как стандарт, имеется практически у всех рсубд

Comment: @Sergeyну в oracle обычно используют nvl или decode :)